# How to validate the angular grid cell value

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new to the angular, I want to validate the value of grid cell.

So here is the example.

this is my .js file

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.grid.cellNav']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.gridOptions =
 {
  rowHeight:45,
  enableSorting: true,
  enableFiltering: false,
  multiSelect: false,
  enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
  enableCellEdit:true,
  columnDefs:
  [
   {
    field: 'firstName',
    displayName: 'First Name',
    enableColumnMenu: false
   },
      {
    field: 'lastName',
    displayName: 'Last Name',
    enableColumnMenu: false
   },
      {
    field: 'company',
    displayName: 'Company',
    enableColumnMenu: false,
    editableCellTemplate:
    "<div><form name=\"inputForm\"><input type=\"INPUT_TYPE\" ng-class=\"'colt' + col.uid\" ui-grid-editor ng-model=\"MODEL_COL_FIELD\"  minlength=5 maxlength=10 required><div ng-show=\"!inputForm.$valid\"><span class=\"error\">To short!</span></div></form></div>"
   },
      {
    field: 'employed',
    displayName: 'Employed',
    enableColumnMenu: false
   }
  ]    
 };

  $scope.gridOptions.data = [
    {
        "firstName": "Hosel",
        "lastName": "Carney",
        "company": "Enormo",
        "employed": true
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Rina",
        "lastName": "Wise",
        "company": "Comveyer",
        "employed": false
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Nanju",
        "lastName": "Waters",
        "company": "Fuelton",
        "employed": false
    }
];

$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi)
{
  $scope.gridApi=gridApi;
};

$scope.addUser=function()
 {
  var _model=
  {
  "firstName": null,
        "lastName": null,
        "company": null,
        "employed": null
  };
   
  $scope.gridOptions.data.unshift(_model);
  setTimeout(function(){
    $scope.gridApi.cellNav.scrollToFocus($scope.gridOptions.data[0], $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[0]);
  }, 100)
  
 };
}]);
```

```css
This is the .css file

.grid {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
This is my HTML file

<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="gridStyle" ui-grid-edit ui-grid-cellnav></div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addUser()">Add row</button>
</div>
```

What I want to do it to validate the company name in each column, if the company name is different. I should show the error.

**see on Plunker**[Click here to see the code online on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5jcuE0VdS9wBggxi05iQ?p=preview)

Comment: It just mean that every user has the same company name, if any user write the different company name it should show an error

Comment: So the new company should be in [Enormo, Comveyer, Fuelton...]?

Comment: Sorry for the misconception, ultimately  values in the company column should always be same, for the time being, I have hard coded the value, If we delete those hard coded value, and if the first user enter the company name as "A" then all the user has to enter the company name as "A". if not then it should show an error